# If $F$ is continuous and $\lim_{\left\|x\right\|\to\infty}F(x)=\infty$, then all niveau sets $\left\{x:F(x)\le\alpha\right\}$ are compact

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, functions

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $$\lim_{\left\|x\right\|\to\infty}F(x)=\infty\tag{1}$$

I want to show that $$N(F,\alpha):=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:F(x)\le\alpha\right\}$$ is compact. Obviously, $$N(F,\alpha)=F^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,\alpha\right]\right)$$ is closed (since it is a preimage of a closed set). It's intuitively clear to me, that $(1)$ implies the boundedness of $N(F,\alpha)$, but how do we need to conclude it formally?

Answer (score 4):

By (1), given $\alpha$, there is an $R > 0$ such that for all $x \in \def\R{\mathbf R}\R^n\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$ with $\abs x \ge R$ we have $F(x) \ge \alpha + 1$. Hence $N(F, \alpha) \subseteq B_R(0)$, as for all $x \in \R^n$ with $F(x) \le \alpha$ we must have $\abs x \le R$, by choice of $R$.

Hence $N(F, \alpha)$ is bounded.